# Failed downgrade - iPod touch with broken home button

Tags: ipod, downgrade

I tried to downgrade my iPod touch 4th gen iOS 6.1.6 to iOS 5.1.1.

I went on Redsn0w clicking extras/even more/restore/ipsw. Then I selected iOS 5.1.1 firmware. I stopped the process halfway. Now my iPod's screen is black and when I plug it into iTunes the device is not recognised.

The problem is that my home button is broken so I cannot press the power and home button to make the screen light up with the apple logo.

What can I do now to fix this issue?

Comment: I might be a bearer of false hope, but I do remember there being a way to restore devices that have broken hardware buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your device into a state called [Recovery Mode](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Recovery_Mode), and then iTunes will automatically detect your device and let you restore to the latest iOS. For an iPod touch 4th gen, there are a few tools that can get your device into Recovery Mode for you without the use of hardware buttons. The best ways are to use [redsn0w](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Redsn0w) or [iRecovery](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IRecovery), but the steps are really complicated to use those utilities. There is a tool called [RecBoot](http://www.cydiaos.com/download-recboot/) that claims to work, but I haven't used it, so I can't speak to it.

**Edit:** I actually had to use RecBoot the other day, and it worked great.